# SwaggerUIBundle hide schemes

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have working on the `swagger-ui` which use the swagger `json` file like:

```
...
...
...
host: example.com
basePath: /
schemes:
- https
swagger: "2.0"
...
...
...
```

Is there any way to not show the **`schemes`** on the web via `swagger-ui`.

I have gone through the documentation for [configuration](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md), but couldn't find anything that I can use. I might be missing something.

Let me know if you have any idea.

My JS code snippet:

```
// above code for swagger-ui stuff
// snippet is just about conf
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    const swaggerUI = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: jQuery("#swagger-ui").data("source"),
        dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis
        ],
        plugins: [
        ],
        layout: "BaseLayout",
        defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1,
    });
    window.swaggerUI = swaggerUI;
});
```

What I want to hide:

[image]

Comment: `defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1` is how you hide the "Schemas" section. You already have this option in your Swagger UI config.

Comment: @Helen, I can see that `Schemes` dropdown still appears that's why I am confused.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? What version of Swagger UI do you use (open the browser dev tools, switch to the Console tab, and evaluate `versions`)

Comment: @Helen I am using "swagger-ui-bundle" and "swagger-ui-standalone-preset"

Comment: What version of Swagger UI? This option was added in v. 3.7.0.

Comment: By using `defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1`, I can see models are hide but not `schemes`

Comment: @Helen I supposed he's using the 3.24 version where his problem is occuring.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the correct way of doing this in versions lower than 3.7 is by creating a custom plugin that removes the schemes component.

```
const HideSchemes = function() {
    return {
      components: {
        schemes: function() { return null }
      }
    }
  }
const swaggerUI = SwaggerUIBundle({
    ...
    plugins: [HideSchemes],
    ...
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  const HideSchemes = function() {
    return {
      components: {
        schemes: function() {
          return null
        }
      }
    }
  }
  const swaggerUI = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json',
    dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis
    ],
    plugins: [HideSchemes],
    layout: "BaseLayout",
    defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1,
  });
  window.swaggerUI = swaggerUI;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.24.2/swagger-ui.css" integrity="sha256-Dw3/dQaA/3PKkN2b3agvmpPhItQwRBufnIRmCYo2vo0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.24.2/swagger-ui-bundle.js" integrity="sha256-vSnFNvuQhNviHFS0M3EXj1LHCYdscvEdVmLIiDDZVhQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
```

You can, in this fiddlen remove the plugins option to see the difference.

https://jsfiddle.net/g60qsdty/

Answer (score -1):

If you are always going to use **http** authentication scheme for swagger you can do following with your swagger json file. **Default** authentication scheme will be **http**.

[image]

Now if you need **https** authentication scheme you have to edit swagger-ui as suggested by "webron" [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3326).

**Method 1:**

Add custom css to the generated swagger html [here](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/124)

**Method 2: (Not Recommended)**

1. Keep your scheme https only
2. Go to this location node_modules > swagger-ui-dist > swagger-ui.css
3. Find **.scheme-container**
4. And add CSS with **display: none;**

   .scheme-container{display: none; margin:0 0 20px;padding:30px 0;background:#fff;box-shadow:0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15)}